# TEdit and WM_PAINT message handler strange behavior

Tags: delphi, vcl, editcontrol

I am trying to implement my own drawing on a `TEdit` control when it does not have focus (show ellipsis in `TEdit` when the editor doesn’t fully display its text). So I starאed with this code:

```
type
  TEdit = class(StdCtrls.TEdit)
  private
    FEllipsis: Boolean;
    FCanvas: TCanvas;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FEllipsis := False;
  FCanvas := TControlCanvas.Create;
  TControlCanvas(FCanvas).Control := Self;
end;

destructor TEdit.Destroy;
begin
  FCanvas.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TEdit.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  if FEllipsis and (not Focused) then
  begin
    // Message.Result := 0;
    // TODO...
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Notice that when `FEllipsis and (not Focused)` the message handler does nothing.

Now I dropped a `TButton` and 2 `TEdit` controls on the form, and added form `OnCreate`:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.FEllipsis := True;
end;
```

I expected `Edit1` to draw normally, and `Edit2` not to draw anything inside the edit control.

Instead the message handler was processed endlessly, `Edit1` was not drawn also, and the entire application was choking (with 25% CPU usage!). I have also tried returning `Message.Result := 0` - same effect.

Now, for the "strange" part: When I obtain the canvas handle with `BeginPaint`, everything works as expected.

```
procedure TEdit.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  PS: TPaintStruct;
begin
  if FEllipsis and (not Focused) then
  begin    
    if Message.DC = 0 then
      FCanvas.Handle := BeginPaint(Handle, PS)
    else
      FCanvas.Handle := Message.DC;
    try
      // paint on FCanvas...
    finally
      FCanvas.Handle := 0;
      if Message.DC = 0 then EndPaint(Handle, PS);
    end;
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Notice I did not call `inherited` either.

How to explain this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When a window is invalidated, it is asked to make itself valid at the next paint cycle. Typically that happens in the main thread message loop when `GetMessage` finds that the queue is empty. At that point `WM_PAINT` messages are synthesised and dispatched to the window.

When the window receives these messages, its task is to paint itself. That is typically done with calls to `BeginPaint` and then `EndPaint`. The call to `BeginPaint` validates the window's client rect. This is the critical piece of information that you are lacking.

Now, in your code, you did not call `inherited` and so did not paint anything, and did not call `BeginPaint` / `EndPaint`. Because you did not call `BeginPaint`, the window remains invalid. And so an endless stream of `WM_PAINT` messages are generated.

The relevant documentation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145194.aspx):

> The **BeginPaint** function automatically validates the entire client area.

Comment: Thanks! The documentation made it clear: *"The system continues to generate WM_PAINT messages until the current update region is validated"*

Comment: This has to be the best brief description of the windows message painting process that I've read yet.